# Why transparent preview?

Tags: macos, bug

I press `Space` at any document. 
I get transparent preview which makes difficult to read anything about the document.
I think this is not a feature of the latest OSX 10.10.3. 
I have reduced transparency maximally in the settings.

Example

[image]

How can you prevent the transparency of previewing files?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that this isn't a feature of OSX. It looks like it is showing you the code of PDF files instead of rendering them as PDF files. My guess is you've either installed a QuickLook plugin that is doing this, or you've installed an application with a QuickLook plugin that is handling files instead of the default plugins.

There are three folders for QuickLook plugins. Please check these folders for any plugins that you've installed yourself that could be doing this. "/System/Library/QuickLook", "/Library/QuickLook" and "/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Library/QuickLook".

Alternatively you can run the command `qlmanage -m plugins` to see a list of plugins on your system. This will tell you the plugins from these folders, but also includes the plugins that come bundled with applications. You could even filter it to just show those that affect PDF files with `qlmanage -m plugins | grep pdf`.

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: This is not the solution to the problem. I will let you know when I get my new Macbook air and report what went wrong in the Macbook Air mid-2013. This bug is probably kernel related, since it is associated with loss of sounds in the system.

Comment: I seriously don't think it has anything to do with the kernel. The kernel isn't involved on that level with drawing windows on the screen. The WindowServer is responsible for drawing windows to the screen and makes decisions about their appearance. And specifically when you select a file and hit SPACE you are invoking the Quick Look feature. So I'd really recommend inspecting the Quick Look set up if you are having issues with this.

Answer (score 0):

Go into Activity Monitor, where you'll see a list of all the processes running on your computer and have the ability to quit them using the leftmost button at the top of the app window. Find the process named "Quick Look UI Helper," quit it, and then try to open a file preview again.

Comment: This event occurs very often. I think to find a real way of stopping this to happen would be most useful. Any idea to prevent creation of such events?

Comment: You could try getting the OS X 10.10.4 update.

Comment: @Masi If you've already done that, you could try a standard OS reinstall. And while you're in Recovery HD to do that, a disk verify and permissions repair couldn't hurt.

Comment: I do not recommend to update to 10.10.4 from 10.10.3. My Macbook Air 2013-Mid went totally silent after this installation and no power anymore in the laptop. I have 5 year waranty in it so no problem.This bug is related to many factors which Apple has not managed to solve. Doing update to 10.10.4 killed the laptop finally. No recovery modes possible. I will get a new laptop from Apple from this because of my warranty.

Comment: Oh god, I'm so sorry.

Answer (score 0):

First try repairing permissions on your startup drive in Disk Utility.  You want to make sure all your quicklook plugins have proper access.  Repairing permissions should fix any problems, if it finds any.

You'll then want to reload the plug ins and clear the cache by running the following 2 terminal commends:

`qlmanage -r` and hit the enter key

`qlmanage -r cache` and hit the enter key

Finally, clear out the preference files for QuickLook located in (your user account)/Library/Preferences.  Delete or move to desktop any files starting with com.apple.quicklook in that folder.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the proposal but this bug is not permissions related.

Comment: what about the rest of the suggestions, did they work?

Comment: No. I will report when Apple gives the report of the failure. Takes 2-3 weeks.